# Application Scope in Website JSP file and Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am trying to use application scope to retrieve items stored in the array list in the application

In my Servlets when I use

```
getServletContext().setAttribute("newUser", new ArrayList<User>());
```

with this

```
ArrayList<User> users = (ArrayList<User>) getServletContext().getAttribute("newUser");
        users.add(user);
```

I can print with

```
for(int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++){

            System.out.println(users.get(i).getUsername());
        }
```

this but they don't show up in the JSP

```
<c:forEach items="${applicationScope.newUser}" var="i">
     ${i.username} ${i.password}<br>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: it should be only "${newUser}". And i'm quite sure you can't set an arraylist like that

Comment: Your code looks good. How do you invoke the servlet? Because you need to invoke the servlet at least once after rebooting the server.